# Has youtube removed native controls?

Tags: youtube-api

I am just checking a video player that was built for a client and found that native controls no longer exist in the youtube player, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as YouTube has introduced their own chrome. At this time it doesn't appear to support rolling back to the previous API version. Sad.

Comment: It looks like the native controls have returned. Ugh, so inconsistent.